# SHA2 Support for Domino 8.5.3 FP6 Server?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

In this [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418982) from IBM you can find the following answers:

> **Q1:** Can I import the SHA-2 cert on a Domino 9.x server and then use that keyring on a Domino 8.5.x server? **No.** Domino 8.5.x lacks the
>   cryptographic infrastructure for SHA-2. This means if you import the
>   cert using 9.x and the Interim Fix and and KYRTool described above,
>   you can use that keyring on a Domino 9.0 or above server, but not on a
>   Domino server pre-Domino 9.0.
>
> **Q2:** Can I get a hotfix on 8.5.x or earlier to support SHA-2?  **No.** This
>   is not possible since releases prior to Domino 9.0 lack the
>   cryptographic infrastructure for SHA-2.

Is an update to `Domino 9.x` the only way the handle this issue? If so, how long it's time, before the relevant web browsers (ie, firefox and chrome) will cancel the support for SHA-1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for long-term, upgrade to Domino 9 is the only solution. As a workaround you could use a reverse-proxy solution, (e.g. using Apache Web Server, NGINX or HAProxy), see https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/6AF303DE836BA02D85257D570058B1CA as an example.

Regarding browsers support of SHA-1:

- Microsoft:
  http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2013/11/12/sha1-deprecation-policy.aspx
- Google:
  http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html
- Mozilla:
  https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to get SHA-2 certificates with Domino 8.5.3 you could install a reverse- proxy in front of domino and let that one handle encryption. But of course then you have two machines and two different software- environments to maintain. And you still have a "very old" software running.

As of [this Link](https://support.servertastic.com/deprecation-of-sha1-and-moving-to-sha2/) the first to abandon SHA-1 Support will be **Microsoft** in **January 2016**. Chrome will show warnings long before that but still accept them. 
**Firefox** will not accept SHA-1 after **January 2017**. 
From that point Chrome will also treat them as "affirmatively insecure".

Best advice: update your servers to 9.0.1 as fast as possible. The effort is minimal and then you can natively handle TLS 1.2

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will upgrade to 9.0.1 as soon as possible :)